# On extjs 5, how to disable an action column item?

Tags: extjs

At first,  one have to  get it, I can only get the `GRIDPANEL`, and cannot get `action column`.

I find #grid >#itemid is null, but  #grid is good.

could anyone help me about this？

Comment: To select your action column use the '#grid actioncolumn' selector

Answer (score 1):

```
        columns: [{
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            items: [{
                isDisabled: me.fnIsDisabled,
                ...



...
fnIsDisabled: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, items , rec){
    return rec.get('global');
},
```

will disable the action in all rows where the corresponding record has property `global` set to `true`.

You won't have to fiddle with the column itself at all...

Comment: I have  a  tabpanel which has 3 tabs. And the grid action column has 3 action column item. when tab 1 is activated,  ActionColumnItem 1 is enabled...I should say earlier.Your solution seems not to work to me.

Comment: Perhaps you just don't know how to change my solution to suit your needs. Depending on your code, which you didn't post, it will be sth. similar to

    fnIsDisabled: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, items , rec){
        return colIndex == grid.up('tabpanel').getActiveTab();
    },

Have you already tried fiddling around a bit?

Comment: grid is not in the tabpanel.  grid parent and tabpanel parent are  the same container.Can tabpanel activation event fires grid  disable its actioncolumnitem?I am not prefer to reload store?